# #selector in gesture Recognizer in xcode9

Tags: ios, gesture-recognition, uiswipegesturerecognizer, ios11

Hii everyone i'm just shifting from xcode8 to xcode9 
and when i tryed to use gesture recognizer they xcode9 is showing some error

> argument of #selector refers to instate method swipe(gesture)  that is not > 
>    expose to obj c
>   and here my code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipe(gestuer:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}

func swipe(gestuer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestuer.direction == .left {
        print("this is left swipe")
    }
}
```

so is it xcode problem of something else

Comment: add @objc before your swipe function

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the @objc attribute on swipe(gestuer:) to use it with #selector.

```
@objc func swipe(gestuer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestuer.direction == .left {
        print("this is left swipe")
    }
}
```

Comment: could you plez explain why i need to use this, where in xcode8 there was nothing such as

Comment: "A Swift class or protocol must be marked with the @objc attribute to be accessible and usable in Objective-C. This attribute tells the compiler that this piece of Swift code can be accessed from Objective-C." because #selector is objective C so you need to make your method accessible with objective C

Comment: i got that but i'm question is this error was not showing in xcode8